# How to make drop align to its parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the code below, I have a link inside a container div, and that link controls a bootstrap drop down menu. Now the drop down menu is aligned to the drop down link itself. how can I change the position of the drop down menu so that it is aligned to the link's parent div and it has the same width as the parent div? Just like the parent div is the drop down button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="widget-body" style="border: solid 1px black; height:45px; margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:20px;background:linear-gradient(to right, #85e2f0 5% , white 95%);">
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:45px; font-size: 28px;">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>            
  <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:30px;text-align:center; border: solid 1px black;margin-top: 6px; display: flex; align-items: center;justify-content: center; background-color: #42d442;">test</div>            
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:43px; font-size: 27px; text-align: center;">
 <a data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a demo of the code:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p0c25p1x/)

Comment: to which parent class are you want to position it?

Comment: the outer div which has the class widget-body

Comment: make `.widget-body` position of relative and `.col-xs-2 open` class a position of static then the dropdown will stick to the parent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css:

```
    .widget-body {
        position: relative;
    }   
    .widget-body .col-xs-2.open {
        position: static;
    }
    .widget-body ul.dropdown-menu {
        right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **margin** attributes to move dropdown ul and for width,check padding and min-width of dropdown ul. Try adjusting them in your browser.

```js
   $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

      var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

      $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
         .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
         .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

      return false;

   });
```

```css
.btn-input {
   display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
   margin-top: -1px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="widget-body" style="border: solid 1px black; height:45px; margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:20px;
                 background:linear-gradient(to right, #85e2f0 5% , white 95%);">
             <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:45px; font-size: 28px;">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
             </div>
              
             <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:30px;text-align:center; border: solid 1px black;
                                          margin-top: 6px; display: flex; align-items: center;
                                          justify-content: center; background-color: #42d442;">
              test
             </div>
              
             <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:43px; font-size: 27px; text-align: center;">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 </a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:-400%; padding:0;min-width:260px;" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the div.open 'col-xs-12' rather col-xs-2 and add this CSS:

```
.open a{
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   top: -42px;
   right: 12px; 
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```